# How to match with RegExp outside of HTML Tags

Tags: html, regex, replace, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

How can I match some alphanumerical words  that *are outside* of an HTML Tag instead of match every words

Example:

```
<div id="mariano mariano mariano" nota="mariano/mariano">mariano was looking forward Mariano. I want to match this "Mariano" too. Mariano</div>
```

In this example I want to match all "Mariano" outside of the tag id.

I think the key of this issue is looking forward for a "<" before a ">" and match that word, but if the regex find ">" before a "<" this means that the word is in the tag,
But I couldn't manage to achieve/produce a Regex for this.

I fail trying to concat this Regex `(?<=^|>)[^><]+?(?=<|$)` with another one.
And my final lowest quality solution was:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var searchFor = new RegExp("((!?<=^|>)" + termino + ")","ig");
var searchFor2 = new RegExp("(" + termino + "(?=<|$))","ig");
var searchFor3 = new RegExp("(!?<=^|[\\s\\.;,])" + termino + "(?=[\\s\\.;,]|$)","ig");
```

but those 3 don't cover all the alternatives.

Edit: Im working with javascript:

```
<script>
container.find("p, span, div, .texto,").each(function() {
var containerText = $(this).html();
for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
    var termino = terms[i];
    // 1st issue ">termino" was remplaced for: ">Pedro"
    var searchFor = new RegExp("((!?<=^|>)" + termino + ")","ig");
    containerText = containerText.replace(searchFor,">Pedroedro");
    // 2nd issue "termino<" was remplaced for: "Pedro"
    var searchFor2 = new RegExp("(" + termino + "(?=<|$))","ig");
    containerText = containerText.replace(searchFor2,"Pedro");
    // 3rd issue "[\.\s,;:]termino[\.\s,;:]
    var searchFor3 = new RegExp("(!?<=^|[\\s\\.;,])" + termino + "(?=[\\s        \\.;,]|$)","ig");
    containerText = containerText.replace(searchFor3," Pedro");
};
$(this).html(containerText);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: [Please do not attempt to parse HTML with Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/451590)

Comment: Give some example of the markup, and the strings, we're looking for. And all text in a document is within, at the very least, the `body` element.

Comment: Regex is not the way to parse HTML.  Please take a look at http://htmlparsing.com for some starting points.

Answer (score 1):

A few things -

1. Welcome to stackoverflow!
2. Please, search for questions before asking.  There are numerous results for parsing
   xml with regex.
3. Don't use regex expressions for parsing xml/html!  [Try xpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Iterator_Example)!

   ```
   var termino = // how ever you were defining before...

   // Give me all divs, where the text content contains value of "termino"
   var iterator = document.evaluate('//div/text()[contains(.,' + termino + ')]', documentNode, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null );

   try {
     // init thisNode to the first item in the iterator
     var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();

     // go through all items, alert their content (which should contain termino)
     while (thisNode) {
       alert( thisNode.textContent );
       thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
     } 
   }
   catch (e) {
      dump( 'Error: Document tree modified during iteration ' + e );
   }
   ```